# Why my Seaborn line plot x-axis shifts one unit?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I am trying to compare two simple and summarized pandas dataframe with line plot from Seaborn library but one of the lines shifts one unit in X axis. What's wrong with it?
The dataframes are:

[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/gazelle/Documents/m3inference/m3_result.csv',index_col='id')
df = df.drop("Unnamed: 0",axis=1)
for i, v in df.iterrows():
    if str(i) not in result:
        df.drop(i, inplace=True)
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'estimated'] = result[str(i)]

m3 = pd.read_csv('plot_result.csv').set_index('id')
ids = list(m3.index.values)
m3 = m3['age'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index().sort_values('index')
m3 = m3.rename(columns={m3.columns[0]:'bucket', m3.columns[1]:'age'})

df_estimated = df[df.index.isin(ids)]['estimated'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index().sort_values('index')
df_estimated = df_estimated.rename(columns={df_estimated.columns[0]:'bucket', df_estimated.columns[1]:'age'})

sns.lineplot(x='bucket', y='age', data=m3)
sns.lineplot(x='bucket', y='age', data=df_estimated)
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: Could you share the rest of the code too? Just a hunch but I've got a feeling that the `[0]`th value of the `index` column is `2`, hence the graph looks shifted one unit right-wards. I'm pretty confident about my hypothesis, so if that's the case then I can share an answer to it.

Comment: Assuming the dataframes are the ones you show, the code generates the correct image. That is to say, the code is ok, the problem probably lies in the data.

Comment: @warped I took a screenshot from my dataframes.

Comment: @Jarmos I put all the requirements.

Comment: Create a [mcve], where the data is created via code (no screenshots, no table dumps). Add the versions of seaborn, pandas and matplotlib in use.

Comment: I copied the data from the dataframes, and plotted them, with your code, and get the right plot. So, the problem is not in the code you posted.

Comment: @GhazalehKharadpoor, as mentioned earlier, the code works as expected. Hence, as I explained earlier already look at the first row from the`m3` DataFrame and then compare it to the first row of the `df_estimated` DataFrame.

Comment: @Jarmos The only difference between two dataframes is their `index`. I do not understand why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out in the comments, the data and code you provide appear to produce the correct result:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

m3 = pd.DataFrame({"index": [2, 3, 4, 1], "age": [123, 116, 66, 33]})
df_estimated = pd.DataFrame({"index": [3, 2, 4, 1], "estimated": [200, 100, 37, 1]})

sns.lineplot(x="index", y="age", data=m3)
sns.lineplot(x="index", y="estimated", data=df_estimated)
plt.show()
```

This gives a plot which is different from the one you posted above:

[image: Resulting plot]

From your screenshots it looks like you are working in a Jupyter notebook. You are probably suffering from the issue that at the time you plot, the dataframe `m3` no longer has the values you printed above, but has been modified.

Comment: So why my plot is like that? I tested it with Matplotlib too but the result was the same. That’s so weird.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that your issues are due to the plotting library, given that this is a standard plot with very few datapoints. Can you reproduce my result (in a clean, new Python file or Jupyter notebook)?

Comment: I don't think that the problem is dataframe modification or something like this. I edited my question and put some extra code. You can see.

Comment: Please provide the values of `m3` and `df_estimated` right before `sns.lineplot`.

Comment: Values were provided with those screenshots.

Comment: As multiple people have now demonstrated, these values are not what is fed into `sns.lineplot`. Further, you are plotting `bucket` and not `index` as the x-axis, so that clearly cannot be the dataframes you use in the script.

Comment: You are right, my final dataframe has been changed because I sorted my dataframes with their bucket columns. Further, I’ve just renamed the columns and nothing more. I will update it ASAP.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve] that others can copy and run on their machine.